# Visual Studio Code install python extension pylint failed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, attributeerror, pylint

Today, I use vscode editor python code ,the vscode remind install pylint. so I install python externsion ,at the same time I  install oylint use cmd `python -m pip install -U pylint --user` in the terminal.
but the terminal report the information of

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    __import__('pip._vendor.packaging.requirements')
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.pyparsing import (
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 4720, in <module>
    _reBracketExpr = Literal("[") + Optional("^").setResultsName("negate") + Group( OneOrMore( _charRange | _singleChar ) ).setResultsName("body") + "]"
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1201, in setResultsName
    newself = self.copy()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1160, in copy
    cpy = copy.copy( self )
AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'copy'
```

at present I can not find an effect measure deal with the problem,so I find help in here,thanks!

Comment: do you have file named `copy.py` in the current working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a module in your workspace named `copy`. Rename that so it doesn't shadow the built-in `copy` module from Python's stdlib and that should let pip run properly.